# How to use operator [] with operator =?

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the alignment of the operator [] and operator =.
I can't understand to write function LinkedList LinkedList::operator=(const int& n) accurately. it does not look like any operator =  that I met through.
Please help me understand the nature of it (together with the code as possible). Thank very much!

**file .h**

```
    class LinkedList
    {
    private:
        Node* pHead;
        Node* pTail;
        int curN;
    public:
        int& operator[](const int& i);
        LinkedList operator = (const int& n);//
    };
```

**file .cpp**

```
  int& LinkedList::operator[](const int& i)
  {
        int tmp;
        if (i < 0)
            tmp = 0;
        else if (i > this->curN)
            tmp = this->curN - 1;
        else
            tmp = i;

        int count = 0;
        Node* pNode = this->pHead;
        while (count < tmp)
        {
            count++;
            pNode = pNode->pNext;
        }
        return pNode->_data;
    }

    LinkedList LinkedList::operator=(const int& n)
    {
        //Problem here
    }
```

**And file main.cpp**

```
 int main()
    {
        srand(1234);
        LinkedList l;
        l[-1] = 9000;
        l[4] = 2000;
        l[100] = 10000;
        cout << l << endl;
    }
```

Comment: As an aside, overloading `operator[]` on a linked list isn't a great design idea. Most people think of `operator[]` as providing constant time access to something, and in the case of your linked list it's providing linear time access.

Comment: Operator `=` is entirely independent. Your code does not use it, and would work as-is.

Comment: Should it work? Is `operator[]` **always** going to find a valid link, and return its data?

Comment: @StoryTeller I think you demand a contract from the overloaded operator the original one doesn't promise. Standard `operator []` doesn't really always return a valid element as well.

Comment: @tofro, unless if by "original" you mean `std::map::operator[]` which always tries to return a valid element.

Comment: @StoryTeller I mean the standard array operator inherited from "C". I do, however, fully agree with Sean's first comment, although constant time expectation isn't necessarily the only assumption `[]` might break on linked lists.

Comment: @tofro, operator overloading doesn't bind you to the same "contracts". You should definitely not change semantics completely, but it's hardly wrong to write with stronger guarantees.

Comment: @StoryTeller  Note I didn't say *wrong*. Consider any added safety an "unexpected service". I would assume `operator []` to return a valid element as long as I stay within the upper and lower bounds. That's obviously not guaranteed by a list that has "holes" in it. On second thought, you might be right for the "holes" case where some safety mechanism would have to be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 l[-1] = 9000;
    l[4] = 2000;
    l[100] = 10000;
```

On this line of codes, `LinkedList::operator=(const int& n)` will not be called, because `LinkedList::operator[](const int& i)` returns a reference to int.

what you want to do is to return a Node on your `LinkedList::operator[](const int& i)`, and define your own `operator=` there.

```
Node& LinkedList::operator[](const int& i)
  {
        int tmp;
        if (i < 0)
            tmp = 0;
        else if (i > this->curN)
            tmp = this->curN - 1;
        else
            tmp = i;

        int count = 0;
        Node* pNode = this->pHead;
        while (count < tmp)
        {
            count++;
            pNode = pNode->pNext;
        }
        return *pNode;
    }

///Your node class
    class Node
    {
       public: 
          int _data;
          Node& operator=(const int data)
          {
              _data = data;
              return *this;
          }
    }
```

**Edit:

Make sure you place pNode somewhere where it can be deleted later to avoid memory leak.**

Comment: I don't think he want to do that. How can he retrieve the value of the node ? I think the purpose of the Node class is to be encapsulated inside the LinkedList class

Comment: @Hugal31 encapsulated data doesnt mean it cannot be read and write

Comment: Yes, but I think the solution of Mr.Duy is quite good. He just don't understand the purpose of the assigment operator.

Comment: i see, i just prefer this kind of linked list design :)

Comment: Now I understand the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `operator=` is for your object, not for its content.

In this case, `LinkedList::operator=(const int& n)` is called:

```
LinkedList l;
l = 5;
```

In you case, only the `LinkedList::operator[]` is called.

```
l[4] = 2000;
```

Comment: Now I understand the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment operator needs to be in the Node class, not the list class.

You are assigning to a Node. To call the list class assignment operator you would have to do something like:

l = LinkedList();

(But that is not what you want)

Comment: Now I understand the problem, thank you!